# Limit the number of file downloads with wget?

Tags: wget

I am trying to download all pdf files from a website using `wget`. I only require `n` files to be downloaded. How can I tell `wget` to stop after downloading `n` files?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there's no [wget](/questions/tagged/wget) switch to do it directely from within `wget`, so :

What I would do :

```
#!/bin/bash

num=10
mech-dump --links http://domain.tld/path |
grep -i '\.pdf' |
while read url; do
    if ((++c <= num)); then
        wget "$url"
    fi
done
```

`mech-dump` is debian package `libwww-mechanize-perl`